# C++ template typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I have a class

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix {
    // ....
};
```

I want to make a `typedef` which creates a `Vector` (column vector) which is equivalent to a `Matrix` with sizes N and 1. Something like that:

```
typedef Matrix<N,1> Vector<N>;
```

Which produces compile error. The following creates something similar, but not exactly what I want:

```
template <size_t N>
class Vector: public Matrix<N,1>
{ };
```

Is there a solution or a not too expensive workaround / best-practice for it?

Answer (score 670, accepted):

C++11 added *alias declarations*, which are generalization of `typedef`, allowing templates:

```
template <size_t N>
using Vector = Matrix<N, 1>;
```

The type `Vector<3>` is equivalent to `Matrix<3, 1>`.

---

In C++03, the closest approximation was:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Vector
{
    typedef Matrix<N, 1> type;
};
```

Here, the type `Vector<3>::type` is equivalent to `Matrix<3, 1>`.

Comment: Oh great, I hadn't seen this part of C++0x and I've been bitching about templated typedef for a while... guess I should have a more thorough read of the final draft.

Comment: Will inheriting constructors make the OP's original solution are more viable solution?

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Depends on his goals. I avoid inheritance when composition will do (and yeah, inheriting constructors will make both of these easier), but I also avoid composition when a typedef will do.

Comment: using does not support specialization if I'm not wrong, so the second option is still useful in many cases.

Comment: @UtkarshBhardwaj  Notice you can combine the two, similar to the way that  `<type_traits>` contains alias declarations such as `std::remove_reference_t` the refer to various specializations of `std:::remove_reference`.