# How to typedef unparameterized template?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ template typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef)

Is it possible to typedef unparameterized template like below?

```
template <class Number>
typedef Pair<Number> Point<Number>;
```

If it is, what syntax should I use? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late. This is a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001240/template-typedef-of-a-template).

```
template <typename First, typename Second, int Third>
class SomeType;

template <typename Second>
using TypedefName = SomeType<OtherType, Second, 5>;
```

Supported by gcc-4.7 and 4.8. IDE probably would need to manual set flag

```
 -std=c11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use typedef inside class:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct container
{
typedef std::vector<T> cont;
};

int main()
{
  container<int>::cont q;
  q.push_back(4);
}
```