# template template parameter in std::pair

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-templates

For a kd-tree I have a `Node` class which looks like following:

```
template<typename DataType, unsigned int Dim>
struct Node
{
    DataType* pos;
    DataType payload;
    struct Node<DataType, Dim>* left;
    struct Node<DataType, Dim>* right;
};
```

I am trying to set up a tuple type that combines the distance from the query node to the found neighbor and the neighbor node itself like so:

```
using std::pair<float, Node<typename DataType, Dim>*> = QueryResult;
```

unfortunately the above code gives me the error:

> [...] error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

So I tried a couple of different things, following some of the threads I found on here.
First I thought maybe the second parameter should be declared without anything, but inside the Node class.

```
using std::pair<float, Node<DataType, Dim>*> = QueryResult;
```

> [...] error: a template-id may not appear in a using-declaration

so then I tried telling the compiler that it is a nested template;

```
using std::pair<float, template Node<typename DataType, Dim>*> = QueryResult;
```

> [...] error: template argument 2 is invalid

There was also a solution using an [adaptor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951683/template-template-parameter-with-wrong-number-of-template-parameters), but that also did not work.
I am unsure how I can set up what I am trying to do here.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. I am not super versed in template programming, but am using this project to increase my knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: `using [new alias' name] = [what it aliases];`. You're using it like `typedef`.

Comment: Greetings, Master Yoda! I took the liberty of rephrasing your question such that it would be better understandable by us, mere mortal - by putting Node definition first, and questions about it later.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing here. Where is this `DataType` expected to come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it.  Unlike a `typedef` a using declaration puts the alias as the fist symbol.  That means

```
using std::pair<float, Node<DataType, Dim>*> = QueryResult;
```

needs to be

```
using QueryResult = std::pair<float, Node<DataType, Dim>*>;
```

If you don't know what `DataType` and `Dim` need to be at that point then you need to make it a template alias like

```
template<typename DataType, unsigned int Dim>
using QueryResult = std::pair<float, Node<DataType, Dim>*>;
```

and then you would use it like

```
QueryResult<type_you_want, dim_you_want> some_name;
```

Comment: I am still unsure where DataType should be coming from. Does OP need a template alias?

Comment: @SergeyA Just added that as I'm not sure as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it seems I got the order wrong.. stupid mistake. The template alias I definitely need, as I want the kdtree to work with a templated point class that has templated datatype and number of dimensions. This solution above seems to work! Again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

as commented:

```
template<typename DataType, unsigned Dim>
using QueryResult = std::pair<float, Node<DataType, Dim>*>;
```