# Parameterized typedef possible?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I was wondering if it is possible to have some kind of parameterized typedef.

To illustrate, in my code I use this typedef:

```
typedef std::queue<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::deque<std::vector<unsigned char> > > UnsignedCharQueue;
```

As you can see this is a rather unwieldy construct so the typedef makes sense. However, if I want to have queues with other datatypes I need to define them beforehand explizitly.

So I was thinking if it were possible to use a construct like this:

```
typedef std::queue<std::vector<T>, std::deque<std::vector<T> > > Queue<T>;

private:
    Queue<unsigned char> mMyQueue;
```

Similar like generics in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++11, you can use template aliases, such as in:

```
template<typename T>
using my_alias = some_class_template<T>;

// ...
my_alias<T> obj; // Same as "some_class_template<T> obj;"
```

So in your case it would be:

```
template<typename T>
using Queue = std::queue<std::vector<T>, std::deque<std::vector<T> > >;
```

Also notice, that in C++11 you do not need to leave a space between closed angle brackets, so the above can be rewritten as follows:

```
template<typename T>
using Queue = std::queue<std::vector<T>, std::deque<std::vector<T>>>;
//                                                               ^^^
```

In C++03 you could define a `Queue` metafunction this way:

```
template<typename T>
struct Queue
{
    typedef std::queue<std::vector<T>, std::deque<std::vector<T> > > type;
};
```

Which you would then use this way:

```
Queue<int>::type obj;
```

If you are using it in a template with parameter `T` (as in the following), do not forget the `typename` disambiguator:

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
    typename Queue<T>::type obj;
//  ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Damn, you're lightning fast. I was going to post this.

Comment: @H2CO3: I was lucky enough to get the new question notification sooner ;)

Comment: @VaughnCato: In the question page... "1 question with new activity"

Comment: It may be good to show a metafunction approach for those without C++11 `using`.

Comment: Thanks! The addtional info helped a lot! The C03 syntax is not perfect but still way nicer then using typedefs. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works like this:

```
template <typename T> using Queue = std::queue<std::vector<T>, std::deque<std::vector<T> > >;
```

Comment: Is it possible that g++ c<ygwin 3.4.4 doesn't understand this? I get expected unqualified-id before "using" on this line. Looks like this is not supported yet. :(

Comment: @Devolus: With g++, make sure to specify -std=c++11 as one of the command-line parameters.