# What does ::type in c++ declaration mean?

Tags: c++, templates, types, keyword

The following code is taken from cpp-netlib but I've seen similar declarations elsewhere.

```
template <class Handler>
struct server : server_base<tags::http_server, Handler>::type 
{
    typedef typename server_base<tags::http_server, Handler>::type server_base;
    typedef server_options<tags::http_server, Handler> options;

    explicit server(options const &options) : server_base(options) {}
};
```

Please can someone explain what the significance is of using `::type` in the declaration. Searching with the word 'type' in the search box is throwing up far too many unrelated results to find an answer.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a workaround since C++98 (and also C++03) does not allow to template typedefs.
If you look into server_base class, you'll see a `typedef` called `type`, whose type depends on the template parameters of server_base. FYI, in C++11 you can use alias declarations. See [C++ template typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef)

Comment: I've never heard of C++99, only C++98 and C99

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc :) Yes, sorry, I mixed up with C99

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a typedef inside a templated class/struct that defines some type. In order to see what it really is either look in sever_base template definition or if using Visual Studio just hover mouse over type - it should show the underlying type as a tooltip

Comment: Reason for downvoting?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted because this _is_ a correct answer to the question.

Comment: I did not downvote. But not everybody uses Visual Studio and this question is not tagged as a Visual Studio question.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, it is a tool for simplifying to access/expose a inner type. Instead of writing a long declaration of a template class, you can just access the type by `::type`. 
This way is widely used in C++ standard library, for example [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant):

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef std::integral_constant<int, 2> two_t;

two_t::type my_constant; // <--- simplified
```