# Why are typedef templates illegal?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

From a practical point of view, I understand that both `typedef` and `test` are somewhat "superfluous" and need to be removed if we want the following code to compile:

```
template< typename type_t >
typedef struct tagTest
{
    int a;
} test;
```

However, I thought that the set of typedef declarations was a subset of the set of declarations. They just happened to have that specific *decl-specifier*. That was my rationalization for

```
typedef struct tagTest
{
    int a;
} test;
```

introducing the identifier `test` **and** declaring the structure `tagTest`. If that interpretation is correct, then the following paragraph from the standard should allow `template` `typedef`'s (although not with the meaning given by the keyword `using`).

> The declaration in a template-declaration shall
>   —
>   (1.1)
>   declare or define a function, a class, or a variable, or
>   —
>   (1.2)
>   define a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, or a static data member of a class
>   template or of a class nested within a class template, or
>   —
>   (1.3)
>   define a member template of a class or class template, or
>   —
>   (1.4)
>   be an alias-declaration.

I cannot see error in my reasoning, yet the conclusion is illegal.

What are the relevant parts of the standard that solve the above conundrum?

---

**UPDATE**
Part of the above reasoning uses the fact that `typedef` `struct` declares a structure. The `typedef` specifier, as far as I understand it, implies that any variables declared are really types. That is, the `typedef` upgrades `test` from a mere variable to a type that is equivalent to the declared `tagTest`. That is why the following code compiles (albeit with a warning).

```
typedef struct tagTest
{
    int a;
};
tagTest t;
```

One of the answers takes care of the superfluous `test`. But, it is possible to use typedef without a declarator [because](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) "Init-declarator-list is optional when declaring a named class/struct/union or a named enumeration"

Comment: Er... None of those cases covers it. The fact that the declaration happens to contain something that would declare a class does not mean that the declaration itself declares a class. The declaration merely defines a type.

Comment: @hvd In C, a typedef containing a tagged struct does declare that struct as well as defining a name that aliases it. Are you saying that C++ is different in this regard?

Comment: @davmac No, we're in agreement about the end effect of such a declaration. I'm saying that the part that causes the struct to be declared is not the declaration itself, just a sub-component of that declaration. And that applies to both C and C++.

Comment: @hvd got it (and I agree). So, yes, a `typedef struct` has the effect of declaring the structure, but is not itself a class (struct) declaration.

Comment: @hdv: a `typedef` declaration is a declaration that instead of declaring variables declares types. It is a declaration nonetheless. The [link shared by Marco A.](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2015-January/038013.html)  argues that a `typedef` declaration without declarators such as `typedef struct S { };` is legal. Because it has no declarators, the typedef is legal albeit superfluous. Since such construct does declare a `struct` sticking a template in front of it should be legal.

Comment: @Hector I understand what you are saying. There is no argument that a typedef declaration is in fact a declaration. A typedef such as the example you give also does have the effect, _indirectly_, of declaring a class (struct). I think the text you quote from the standard is trying to say that the declaration should _directly_ declare a class (and this is how compiler implementors seem to have interpreted it). But certainly, this is not explicated and is arguably ambiguous.

Comment: @davmac: Perhaps, I should get the official C++11 standard. I have the N4431 draft. The paragraph [basic.def] lists those declarations that are not definitions. As far as I can tell, that list helps to limit the set of definitions as a subset of the set of declarations.

Comment: @Hector my bad, I was skimming and somehow misread the start of that paragraph. You are right that [basic.def] it is not a complete list of declaration types; I have deleted that comment. However, my earlier comment stands, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Template typedefs](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm) weren't allowed pre-C++11 and with C++11 [template aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) were introduced to address those issues. Cfr. [C++ template typedefs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2795024/1938163) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Template_aliases).

Since, as you noted, the standard doesn't allow `typedef` to be in there, the code is invalid

> alias-declaration:
>
> ```
>  using identifier attribute-specifier-seqopt= type-id ;
> ```

`typedef` declarations are not *alias declarations*.

Furthermore you can't have a declarator if you're declaring a class template, it is explicitly forbidden by the standard

*[temp]/p3*

> In a template-declaration, explicit specialization, or explicit instantiation the init-declarator-list in the declaration
>   shall contain at most one declarator. **When such a declaration is used to declare a class template,
>   no declarator is permitted**.

so not even the following will compile

```
template< typename type_t >
struct tagTest
{
    int a;
} test;
```

---

Edit:

It is nowhere specified that

```
typedef struct S { };
```

should be an error, thus both gcc and clang accept it with a warning. I assume Clang counts on *[temp]/3* to issue an error in case typedef was being used with a template while gcc rejects this code immediately

```
template<typename T>
typedef struct S { };
```

cfr. clang bug [22249](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2015-January/038013.html)

Comment: Removing the `test` token but keeping the `typedef` specifier should be legal because the declarators are optional.

Comment: @Hector edited the question to add details for that case

Comment: +1 That link about clang is nice. But regarding your opening paragraph, I do not argue that `template<typename T>typedef struct S{};` should work in the same way as the `using` keyword. I argue that the standard allow it to be legal with the same meaning as `template<typename T> struct S{};`.

Comment: I'll research further in this gcc/clang difference. For now I'm more inclined into thinking that gcc is right in rejecting it. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Independently from what the `typedef` defines, that is a `typedef` declaration, which is not listed in those cases:

- [member] function
- [member] class
- variable
- member enumeration
- static data member of a class template/of a class nested within a class template
- member template of a class or class template
- alias declaration

And just to be clear `typedef` declarations are not *alias declarations*. *Alias declaration*, as specified by the grammar at §7 of the standard are:

> *alias-declaration*:
>
> `using identifier attribute-specifier-seqopt= type-id ;`

Not to mention that if this was possible, then template `using` declaration would not be nearly as "cool" as they are today, and [there would be little to no sense to have both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23196675/493122).

Comment: I think OPs point is that the text does _not_ say the declaration must _be_ a "[member] class" declaration (amongst the other types), but rather that it "shall declare or define" a class, which a typedef with a struct sub-declaration arguably does.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support templates and the

```
typedef struct tagX {
} X;
```

syntax in C++ is vestigial C, there to allow continued support for C headers etc, not for use in actual C++.

The C++ syntax for the above is

```
struct X {};
```

(YMMV on brace placement)