# Can I change the meaning of `int arr[N]` using `typedef` or `using`?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I write a templated `typedef` or `using`, such that

```
int arr[N];
```

is actually either

```
std::vector<int> arr(N);    /// C++03
```

or

```
std::array<int, N> arr;    /// C++11
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2795024/2425366). Can I write something similar to this

```
template <std::size_t N>
using int[N] = std::array<int, N>;
```

or a templated typedef

```
template <std::size_t N>
typedef int std::array<int, N> [N];
```

Also, I want the same with `char[]` and `std::string`. Is it possible ?

**EDIT** This is what I want to do

```
int arr[10];    // Declare an int array but use it as std::vector
arr.resize(20);
...   // Other methods from std::vector class
```

Comment: What do you mean "such that `int arr[N];` is actually ..."? `int[N]` **is** `int[N]`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The `using` statement I followed from linked answer works well, but is not what I want.

Comment: @Shreevardhan this sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X, think that Y is the solution, so you ask about Y when you run into problems. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Even after the edit, the question makes no sense - you are describing your attempted solution, NOT the actual problem. If you want a `vector<int>`, `define a vector<int>`.  You should know though that `vector` creates a *new* int array internally when you call resize, copies the old data and switches it with the old internal copy. You can also use a `vector<int>` wherever an `int[]` is required. So why this question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wanted that if I declare an int array it should change to a vector. I basically want Java like syntax here.

Comment: @Shreevardhan: You're not listening. That is not what people are asking. People want to know _why_ you "want that if you declare an int array it should change to a vector".

Comment: why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: If you could give `int` another meaning, how would you then express the actual `int` as in `int main`?

Comment: @Shreevardhan then just use a `vector<int>`.  That's what everyone who is going to read your code will expect.

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with what you say. I was only looking for ways to avoid writing `std::vector<int> arr(N)` every time, making it shorter and simpler.

Comment: @Shreevardhan: If that is honestly your only use case here then I must say even considering this is a pretty terrible idea.

Comment: @Shreevardhan You may alias it to something simpler like `template<size_t N> using v_i = std::vector<in> arr(N)`.

Comment: @black: Yeah, you could, if it were valid syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean that you want to change the meaning of `int[N]` to actually be a `std::vector` or `std::array`…

**No, you can't do that.**

Array-declarator notation like `int[N]` is completely fixed as a language construct and cannot be re-purposed.

Comment: @Shreevardhan: What do you mean "alternative to this"? Alternative to what? What is your goal?

Comment: @Shreevardhan what are you actually trying to do? What is the real problem? Whatever it is, changing the fundamentals of the language is *not* the solution

Comment: "No, you can't do that." *Fortunately* you can't touch it, at least for arrays. You can, bravely, do `#define int double`.

Comment: @black: Not without invoking UB you can't.

Comment: Probably the closest you could come is `auto arr = _<int>()[N];` very elegant imho xD