# How to typedef a std::array with a unspecified size?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias, typedef

I want to write some variables like

```
std::array<double, array_num> a;
```

where `array_num` is a `const int` representing the length of the array. But it's long and I want to create an alias for it:

```
typedef std::array<double, array_num> my_array;
```

Is it right? How can I use `my_array` like `my_array<3>`?

Comment: A `std::array`  has a *constant* dimension expression. It cannot be a variable. If you want it to be a variable, you want `std::vector`  or perhaps some future `std::dynarray`  (in some future standard for C++)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you need is an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template <size_t S>
using my_array = std::array<double, S>;
```

You cannot directly make a `typedef` template, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef).

<sup>`size_t` is the type of the second template parameter `std::array` takes, not `int`.</sup>

<sup>Now that you know about `using`, you should be using that. It can do everything what `typedef` does, plus this. Also, you read it from left to right with a nice `=` sign as a delimiter, as opposed to `typedef`, which might hurt your eyes sometimes.</sup>

---

Let me add two more examples of use:

```
template <typename T>
using dozen = std::array<T, 12>;
```

And if you wanted to create an alias for `std::array`, such as it is, you'd need to mimic its template signature:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
using my_array = std::array<T, S>;
```

- because this is not allowed:

```
using my_array = std::array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `using` is really better, and so is `size_t`.

Comment: `size_t` is the type of the second `std::array` template parameter, and it is used for sizes of all standard containers. On x86-64, `int` has 4B, while `size_t` has 8B. You simply don't want `int` messing around there. It's not even `unsigned`.

Comment: @yikouniao Added some additional info, and also, the template argument cannot be a variable, as you phrased it in your question.