# Can std::priority_queue declaration be shortened without specialization?

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

I hope and think this question is not a duplicate of [C++ template typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef) so here goes:

I'm wondering if the community can help me see if there's a way to shorten `template<typename ORDER> std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, ORDER>` with a `typedef` **without** specializing. I'd like to discount `#define`s for this answer, please. I'm not sure if C++11's `alias` feature is applicable here, but I will also need to discount its use as an answer because the compiler I'm working with is C++03.

For context here is some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

namespace
{

template<typename ORDER>
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, ORDER> GetPriorityQ(std::vector<int> numbers)
{
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, ORDER> theQueue;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        theQueue.push(numbers[i]);
    }

    return theQueue;
};

class Less
{
public:
    operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a < b);
    }
};

class More
{
public:
    operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return (b < a);
    }
};

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v({4, 9, 2, 8});

    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Less> pqLess = 
        GetPriorityQ<Less>(v);

    std::cout << "Ordered by Less:" << std::endl;
    while (!pqLess.empty())
    {
        std::cout << pqLess.top() << std::endl;
        pqLess.pop();
    }

    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, More> pqMore = 
        GetPriorityQ<More>(v);

    std::cout << "Ordered by More:" << std::endl;
    while (!pqMore.empty())
    {
        std::cout << pqMore.top() << std::endl;
        pqMore.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware that I could shorten a *specialization* of the priority queue with something like...

```
typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Less> LessQueue;
```

...but I'm wondering if there's a way to shorten it *without* the specialization, so that I can keep `GetPriorityQ(...)` generic (i.e. if I specialized the typedef of the `priority_queue`, I'd have to implement as many specializations of `GetPriorityQ(...)` which I want to avoid).

I.e., in pseudocode, is there a way to do something like:

```
typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, ORDER> OrderedQ

...

template<typename ORDER>
OrderedQueue<ORDER> GetPriority(std::vector<int> numbers)
{
   ...
}

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
    OrderedQueue<Less> pqLess = GetPriorityQ<Less>(v);
    ...
}
```

The reason why I ask is that the length of the line to define a `priority_queue` gets pretty long, even in this simplified example. The actual code I'm working on, which this example is a simplification of, is much longer and hence difficult to read.

Answers don't necessarily need to be `typedef` per se. Anything C++03-compatible and not using `#define` is okay.

Thank you.

Comment: `using` is capable of taking template parameters. _"Anything C++03-compatible and not using #define is okay."_ Looks like you're doomed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you know how to pull this off, could you post an answer? I've literally only used the 'using` keyword for things like `using namespace std` and I can't see how it can be wielded to this situation.

Comment: Not with pre c++11 anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C++03 you can't avoid some verbiage, namely (in template code) `typename`, but apart from that:

```
template< class Order >
struct Pq
{
    typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Order> T;
};
```

So now you can write e.g. `Pq<OrderA>::T`, which is shorter. Or, when `OrderA` is a template argument, `typename Pq<OrderA>::T`.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

---

In other news:

- ALL UPPERCASE is an eyesore, and using it for anything else but macro names conflicts with the common convention for macro naming.

Comment: That's clever. Now I kind of see the utility of class-scoped typedefs. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about little confusion about `typename` there. It's late in the day for me. I had to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the naming convention, too. I'd somehow developed the notion that ALLCAPS was used for template typenames too.

Comment: @StoneThrow: Only for single character template type argument names. Which doesn't conflict because single character names are not used for macros. Usually. Probably best to stay away from `S`. ;-)