# How to introduce a struct in the std namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

We currently use C++11.
`std::optional` is missing from C++11 - it has been introduced in C++17.
Luckily, I found an implementation which has the same interface as `std::optional` and works in C++11 (https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional)

This defines `optional` in `namespace tl`.
So, I can use it like so:

```
#include "optional.hpp"

tl::optional<int> to_int(string str) {
    if (...) { return atoi(str); } 
    else     { return tl::nullopt; }
}
```

However,
I am looking for a way to call this as if `std::optional` was available:

```
#include "optional.hpp"

std::optional<int> to_int(string str) {
    if (...) { return atoi(str); } 
    else     { return std::nullopt; }
}
```

This way, when we switch to C++17, I will not have to replace each `tl::optional` with `std::optional`.
I will only have to replace the contents of the "optional.hpp" header with:

```
// optional.hpp 
// ------------
#include <optional.hpp>
```

Today, this header is implemented as:

```
// optional.hpp 
// ------------
#include "tl/optional.hpp"   // include the official header, when C++17 is available
```

How can I create some sort of an alias in this header, so that when I call `std::optional` it will actually refer to the `tl::optional` ?

- I cannot touch the original code of `tl/optional.hpp`.
- I would prefer not to use a macro

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2795024/1563833

Comment: Use [Boost optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) instead? Generally adding anything to the `std` namespace (except in a few and very limited situations) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `namespace grim { using tl::optional; }` Use `grim::optional` everywhere.  Change the using in Grim's one header to `using std::optional;` when you've moved to C++17, assuming they are API surface compatible.  Otherwise if not drop-in compatible, you'll also need to cleanup the callsites too.

Comment: [Extending the namespace std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) says: _"It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std"_

Comment: @Wyck, if C++11 is not aware of the existence of `std::optional`, it realistically wouldn't hurt if introduced it.

Comment: Replacing "tl::optional" with "std::optional" is one global search-and-replace operation (or one `sed` command), and it will take seconds. Don't waste your time.

Comment: If they say it is undefined behaviour, it is.  You cannot define the behaviour with any definition of your own.  undefined behaviour is exactly that.  Which could include destroying my house, so please don't.

Comment: @GrimFandango that's groovy right up until you find there's already something named `optional` buried in `std` and not exposed.

Comment: @Eljay, my biggest issue is with introducing `tl::nullopt` inside the `std` namespace. `tl::nullopt` is a `constexpr` function that returns a `tl::nullopt_t`.
I've tried writing: `namespace std { using nullopt = tl::nullopt; }` but I get an error: `"nullopt" is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: this std::optional reading about UB is entirely std::optional https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior

Comment: @Wyck, I guess you're right -- Eljay's proposal seems the most promising one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to introduce a struct in the std namespace

By writing a proposal to the standards committee. But in this case the class is already adopted, so what you need to do to get the class is start using the new version of the standard.

> How can I create some sort of an alias in this header, so that when I call std::optional it will actually refer to the tl::optional ?

As not-the-standard-library-implementer, you are not allowed to introduce classes into the std namespace.

What you can have instead, is an alias in your own namespace:

```
namespace my_very_own {
    using tl::optional; // change to std::optional when possible
}
```

Comment: I have issues moving the tl::nullopt inside this namespace.
`namespace my_very_own { using tl::nullopt' }` does not seem to work -- `nullopt` is not a typename

Comment: @GrimFandango I could not reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/4cfYxT Create a [mcve]

Comment: for some reason, I wrote:
`namespace my_very_own { using optional = tl::optional; }`  and it worked.
But this one, didn't: `namespace my_very_own { using nullopt = tl::nullopt; }`

Your answer is fine

Comment: @GrimFandango My initial answer was closer to that since I didn't remember this shorter syntax. That works with types only; not variables. The plain `using` does work with variables too.

Comment: @GrimFandango `using X = Y;` only works with types and namespaces. `t1::optional` is a type, but `t1::nullopt` is neither, it is actually a *constant* of type `t1::nullopt_t`.  You can use `namespace my_very_own { using t1::nullopt; }` instead, it works fine: [Demo](https://ideone.com/nkVrNH)